# Как настроить Binding выбранных элементов из ListView во ViewModel? WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

Есть ListView, в котором отображаются снепшоты. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда выбрано два снепшота, кнопка "сравнить" становилась активна и если выбрано больше одного, то становилась активна кнопка "сохранить". Но я никак не могу понять, как настроить биндинг во ViewModel, ведь в xaml коде чего-то вроде `SelectedItems` или `SelectedIndexes` нет. Раньше все было настроено через костыли в code behind, но сейчас пытаюсь реализовать MVVM и здесь у меня проблемы, ибо я только начал разбираться с этим паттерном. Как это сделать? Может проще будет с другим контейнером?

Comment: Всё там есть, задайте имя ListView, используйте биндинг так: {Binding ElementName=yourListView, Path=SelectedItems}

Comment: *ведь в xaml коде чего-то вроде SelectedItems* — на самом деле есть, но оно только для чтения, поэтому привязку к нему сделать нельзя, но можно передать параметром